# Finding expected number of distinct binomial random variables

Tags: probability

Let $X_i$ be i.i.d. binomial random variables distributed as $B(n,1/4)$. If we consider $m$ such random variables, $X_1,\dots, X_m$, how can we work out the expected number of distinct $X_i$? We can assume $m>n$ and both are large.

Comment: Next time, try to add some personal input.

Comment: @Did Good point. Will do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $0\le k\le n$, define the Bernoulli random variable $U_k$ as follows:
$$
U_k = \left\{
\begin{array}
&0 & \mbox{if there exists}\ i\ \mbox{such that}\ X_i=k\\
1 & \mbox{otherwise}
\end{array}
\right.
$$

In other words, $U_k$ is one iff the value $k$ is not assumed by any $X_i$. Note that this happens with probability $$\left(1-\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac 1 4\right)^k\left(\frac 3 4\right)^{n-k}\right)^m.$$

Then the number of distinct $X_i$ will be equal to $$Z:= n-\sum_{k=0}^n U_k$$ and by the linearity of expectation we have:
\begin{align}
E[Z]&= n-\sum_{k=0}^n E[U_k]\\
&=n-\sum_{k=0}^n \left(1-\binom{n}{k}\left(\frac 1 4\right)^k\left(\frac 3 4\right)^{n-k}\right)^m
\end{align}

Comment: That is nice and clean reasoning. Thank you.